# Lottery Probability Statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

You have a Lottery ticket consisting of the seven numbers that you pick. The seven numbers are chosen from a pool of 49 numbers (1 through 49 inclusive), without replacement. What is the probability that four of your numbers match with the seven winning numbers?

My thinking:

The first choice has 49 options, followed by 48, 47, 46, 45,44,43.

Since only 4 numbers need to match the probability the first number matches is 1/49, the second number 1/48, third 1/47, fourth 1/46.

Multiplying these together you get 0.000000197. Is this the probability or do you need to divide this number by (49*48*47*46*45*44*43)?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly $4$:

$$\frac{\binom{7}{4}\cdot\binom{49-7}{7-4}}{\binom{49}{7}}$$

At least $4$:

$$\sum\limits_{n=4}^{7}\frac{\binom{7}{n}\cdot\binom{49-7}{7-n}}{\binom{49}{7}}$$